# html5 file system api - chrome hangs and crashes in multiple read and writes

Tags: html, google-chrome, fileapi

I have a background thread(web worker) fetching heavy images from server and writing them to the file system synchronously.
At the same time, user needs to scroll through images which have been written already into the file system. So each time a scroll event is fired, a file is read from the file system asynchronously and displayed in the canvas. This process generates simultaneous reads and writes if a user scrolls through multiple images at once and hence causes the browser to hang and eventually crash. How can I be able to accomplish this without getting the browser to hang?

Answer (score 0):

*Please note: this is a wild guess on what is happening, one can never be 100% sure without knowing what actually your code does.*

Chances are, your approach requires a lot of JS heap memory (e.g. you never cache images already read but re-read them discarding previous data.) Hangs may result from multiple full GC's in V8, and the eventual crash results from V8 running out of memory.

I suggest that you use Chrome Developer Tools' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) `Profiles` panel and take a few heap snapshots before the tab crashes. Then you can compare them (the right SELECT in the bottom status bar, choose "Objects allocated between Snapshots 1 and 2") to see the if this hypothesis is right or not.

Comment: Actually I was able to narrow it down by looking at the cpu utilization by chrome. Even when you're writing a single line of text to a file using the File System API, cpu utilization goes to 100% for a second and then comes back to normal. Now here in my case when I was writing 50 files continuously, the CPU utilization was about 100% for the whole time the loop was running. So if I try to do some operations in the foreground, the browser obviously hangs. I thought chrome would be handling the writes in a more optimal way.

Comment: Things are clear now. Could you file a bug on this at http://new.crbug.com (you need to report your Chrome version and OS, which I do not know)?